# Celery Flower Django

Tags: django, celery

i'm doing some tests with the stack: Django, RabbitMQ, Celery and Flower.

Everything is going fine, but we have a problem with failed tasks, i know that they can't be restarted from the Flower web interface (i'm right?), so what i've started celery...

Im my view, i have a dump code that does this job:

```
@app.task(max_retries=2, default_retry_delay = 1 * 1)
def debug_task():
    try:

        random_int = int(randint(0, 15))
        if random_int > 5:
            raise Exception ('> 5')
        else:
            print('Request: {0!r}'.format('OK'))


    except MaxRetriesExceededError:
        print('New queue')
        debug_task.apply_async(queue='failed_tasks')
    except Exception as exc:
        raise debug_task.retry(exc=exc)
```

It's seems to work, due to the fact that i'm seeing in flowers that when the number it's > 5 the entire procedure will be executed another time, as you can see in the screenshot: [image: FLOWER]

So, now i have a bunch of failed tasks and i need "something" that will restart them, execute and give back the result to flower, what i'm doing wrong?

[image: Failed Tasks]

Comment: Could you explain why you use `max_retries=2`?  If set to None, it will never stop retrying.

Comment: Due to that i don't need to retry the procedure endlessly, but i want to execute it manually

Comment: As I know, is not possible to restart task from outside. I mean, solution 'from box'. You can rerun failed tasks with the same arguments, but in this case you will see different tasks in Flower.